# How to increment primary key during postgres COPY batch insert?

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a table with `serial` id constraint:

```
id serial NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pricing_cache_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

Now I want to use the `postgres` COPY command to batch insert csv data into the table.

```
COPY tablename FROM STDIN WITH CSV;
```

Problem: the csv file if course does not have an ID column. How can I batch insert the rows and automatically increment the IDs in the database?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `copy` command allows you to specify which columns to populate. If you omit the `id` column, it will be populated with the values from the sequence:

```
copy pricing_cache (column_1, column_2) from stdin with csv
col_1_value,col_2_value
col_1_value,col_2_value
\.
```

You haven't shown us your complete table definition. The above statements assumes that there are two columns named `column_1` and `column_2` in your table (in addition to the `id` column) and that the input data contains values for those two columns separated by a comma (because of the `with csv`)

Comment: Yes indeed I have multiple colums that are to be populated from csv. I tried leaving the `id` field blank during copy insert *without* specifying the column names in the copy command. So if I got you right, specifying the columns explicit and omitting the id does the trick?

Comment: @membersound: yes, if you leave out the column list, `copy` assumes that the input data contains **all** columns (this is similar to an `insert` with and without a column list)