# psycopg copy_expert doesn't work if id is not in csv

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

I have a data insert goal in Postgres. My table's columns:

id, col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4, col_5, col_6, col_7

Id column is auto incremented.

### My Python insert code

```
copy_table_query = "COPY my_table (col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4, col_5, col_6, col_7) FROM STDIN WITH (DELIMITER '\t');"

curs.copy_expert(copy_table_query, data)
```

But it tries to insert `col_1` into `id` and of course it fails with `psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation: invalid input syntax for type bigint`. Because col_1 is string.

How can I let Postgres generate ids while I just insert data from CSV?

Comment: This should work. Most likely the error is somewhere else, not related to `id`.

Comment: @klin Thank you! I'm glad that the code is fine. It will be easier to fix for me.

Comment: @klin Do you have an example to check out?

Comment: See [How to increment primary key during postgres COPY batch insert?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29963242/1995738) More information in the question (table definition, sample lines of the text file, the entire piece of Python code with COPY) would increase your chances of getting a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Example that shows it works. There is really no need to use `copy_expert` you can use [copy_from](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_from. By default the separator is `tab`. You specify the columns with the `columns` parameter.

```
cat csv_test.csv                                                                                                                                                          
test    f
test2   t
test3   t

\d csv_test
                                 Table "public.csv_test"
 Column |       Type        | Collation | Nullable |               Default                
--------+-------------------+-----------+----------+--------------------------------------
 id     | integer           |           | not null | nextval('csv_test_id_seq'::regclass)
 col1   | character varying |           |          | 
 col2   | boolean           |           |          | 

with open('csv_test.csv') as csv_file:
    cur.copy_from(csv_file, 'csv_test', columns=['col1', 'col2'])
con.commit()

select * from csv_test ;
 id | col1  | col2 
----+-------+------
  1 | test  | f
  2 | test2 | t
  3 | test3 | t
```